# .net core 2.0 with akka.net and f#

Tags: asp.net-core, f#

I have tried to create basic akka.net sample in asp.net core2.0 using f#.Although sample project does not have any error but showing warnings as below

warning NU1701: Package 'Akka.FSharp 1.2.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

and same warning for all packages.
can I get the solution to resolve this warning?

Comment: F# packages for Akka.NET don't target .NET Core yet.

Comment: However you can try Orleans https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Orleans.Core/2.0.0-beta2 which released a beta2 for .NET Core 2. Orleans is similar to Akka, but uses a virtual actor model and methods with code generation rather than messages. Or Orleankka for a more functional/message based approach

Comment: Tseng, Akka.NET is already .NET Standard 1.6+ compatible and it supports Mono from the beginning. You can use it with F# if you like. The question was explicitly about the state of F#-specific wrappers around it.

Comment: It has been 3 years from this question but its the only thing that popups when I google. Did you find any solution? All questions regarding this date to 2017 looks like this is a dead end?